# TLS secure without certificate?

Tags: java, security, ssl, certificate, ca

I wanted to implement TLS to my Java application (which currently implements no kind of encryption). Then I read a little bit more about TLS and saw, that I should use certificates.

So my question  is: Is TLS also secure if I don't use certificates?

And then: If it isn't secure without:
How do I create such a certificate? What are good CAs? Where can I get a certificate for free? And how can I implement the certificate into my server application in Java?

Please note that I'd need a certificate just for one server. Not for me or for an email address.

Comment: You need to learn a bit on TLS - your question is too broad to be answered in current form.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Could you send me some links, please?

Comment: Books are recommended here: https://www.eldos.com/forum/read.php?FID=7&TID=1842 and there are several articles on SSL/TLS and on certificates here: https://www.eldos.com/sbb/articles/65-184.php

Answer (score 4):

> So my question is: Is TLS also secure if I don't use certificates?

It depends on the cipher suite you choose. If you use the dominant model of Server Authentication only, then you probably need server certificates due to the offering of cipher suites like `DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA` or `EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA`. `DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA` or `EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA` require the use of a server certificate.

However, if you allow anonymous cipher suites like Anonymous Diffie-Hellman (ADH), then a server certificate is not needed.

Additionally, if you are using `TLS-PSK` or `TLS-SRP`, then a server certificate is not needed. PSK is Pre-Shared Key; and SRP is Secure Remote Password. There are 88 cipher suites dedicated to PSK and SRP by IANA (see [Transport Layer Security (TLS) Parameters](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.txt)).

PSK and SRP provide mutual authentication and channel binding. That is, both parties prove knowledge of the shared secret without doing dumb things like putting the secret on the wire in the plain text as with `basic_auth` schemes. If one (or both) parties don't know the secret, then channel setup fails and no information is leaked.

PSK and SRP have the **most** desirable security properties of all the SSL/TLS cipher suites. If possible, you should always use them.

---

> And then: If it isn't secure without: How do I create such a certificate?

That's an exercise left to the reader.

---

> What are good CAs?

In my opinion, none of them. There's no reason to confer trust to a third party.

To add insult to injury, the Public CAs don't warrant what you expect and try to shed all of their liability in their Certification Practice Statement (CPS). For example, here's an excerpt from [Apple Inc. Certification Authority Certification Practice Statement](http://images.apple.com/certificateauthority/pdf/Apple_AAI_CPS_v4.0.pdf):

```
2.4.2. CA disclaimers of warranties
To the extent permitted by applicable law, Subscriber agreements,
if applicable, disclaim warranties from Apple, including any
warranty of merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.

2.4.3. CA limitations of liability
To the extent permitted by applicable law, Subscriber agreements,
if applicable, shall limit liability on the part of Apple and shall
exclude liability for indirect, special, incidental, and
consequential damages.
```

So, Apple is selling you a product with no warranty and that offers no liability!!! And they want you to trust them and give them money... what a racket! And its not just Apple - other CAs have equally obscene CPS'es.

---

> Where can I get a certificate for free?

Try [StartCom](https://www.startcom.org/).

They are not *exactly* free, but they are issued for free. If you need a StartCom certificate revoked, then you will have to pay. That's because the cost is in revocation, not issuance. (Other CAs charge you up-front for the revocation, and then pocket the money if unused).

---

> And how can I implement the certificate into my server application in Java?

That depends on your application. We know nothing about your app, so we can't say.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create a self-signed certificate. It will be secure as well, but it will red-flag on most  machines that aren't set up to trust that certificate (whether in the java keystore or otherwise).

Run:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias [certname] -keyalg EC -keysize 571 -validity 730 -keystore javakeystore_keepsecret.jks
```

with `keytool` specified as a full path (depends on OS and how you set up Java).

You can then export the public cert with:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore javakeystore_keepsecret.jks -alias [certname] -file [somefilename]
```

and users can then import the file that is created in order to trust it.

Comment: There are no users. It's just internal communication inside a network. So using these commands I can create a Self-Signed certificate for my application? Don't I need a Certification Authority?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock Yes, and then you can load the keystore in your server program to use TLS.

Comment: How can I tell the clients that the created certificate is the right one?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock Import it in their keystores after exporting it with the second command. If the clients are not Java just install the cert to the OS keystore (depends on OS)

Comment: So using your method I am able to bypass the requirement of a Certificate Authority. Right? And is it save against MITM attacks?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46273/discussion-between-minecraftshamrock-and-hexafraction)

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock I am unable to visit chat at this time. I have to continue with other work in but a few minutes.

Comment: Another question: Now where I have my Keystore .jks file how an I make my server and clients use it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is TLS also secure if I don't use certificates?

No. From [RFC 2246](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt):

> Warning: Completely anonymous connections only provide protection
>           against passive eavesdropping. Unless an independent tamper-
>           proof channel is used to verify that the finished messages
>           were not replaced by an attacker, server authentication is
>           required in environments where active man-in-the-middle
>           attacks are a concern.

and

> The system is only as strong as the weakest key exchange and
>    authentication algorithm supported

Comment: TLS-SRP is a secure way to do TLS without certificates.